# What is the git(1) equivalent of "cvs export"?

Tags: git

What is the git(1)-based equivalent of the "cvs export" command, which checks-out a snapshot of the repository without needing or creating any administrative files (imagine that this is the first step executed by an independent continuous-integration server). Does the git(1) equivalent use the `git archive` command?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, `git-archive` is what you want.